# Extract an integer from a string and replace

Tags: c#, string, file, integer, extract

I'd like to create a program that will go through a file (XML), find out a specific tag, will extract the integer from it and add a value to it, some like a replacement.

I know about the `StreamWrite` function but I'd need some help with the extracting-adding value-replacing thingy. I also would need to use the "\d+"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you created it or _will_ you created it? If you did, show your work first and tell where you stuck exactly. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Since you're working with XML and specific tags, do read the document as XML and use XPath to traverse it. No reason to handle it as normal text.

Comment: I will create it. I'm in a planning mode right now so see how I will do it. Reading about different function I may need for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with **System.Xml.Serialization** wich allow you to convert xml to objects and objects to xml and so you can do what you want.

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)